# Drag edges of imageview to resize in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, imageview, resize

Dears, I'm about to make a Java/JavaFX for my own experience. What this program is supposed to do is to load some images and do some resize and labeling on them. I need to implement resize functionality on imageview which I create dynamically at runtime in JavaFX. I don't know how to do that. Can someone give me a hand?

Here it is my code:

FXML file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ToolBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>


<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="768.0" prefWidth="1024.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/16" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.me.code.HelloController">
   <children>
      <VBox fx:id="imageList" layoutY="44.0" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="677.0" prefWidth="1024.0" />
      <Button layoutX="904.0" layoutY="733.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#finishButtonHandler" text="Finish" />
      <ToolBar layoutY="4.0" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="319.0">
        <items>
          <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#rightButtonHandler" text="Right" />
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#leftButtonHandler" text="Left" />
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#addImageButtonHandler" text="Add Image" />
        </items>
      </ToolBar>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Controller file:

```
package com.me.code;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;




import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class HelloController implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    private VBox imageList;

    @FXML
    void addImageButtonHandler(ActionEvent event) {

        Image img = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("sample_image.jpg"), 100, 100, false, false);
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView();

        imageView.setImage(img);
        imageView.toFront();
        imageView.setVisible(true);

        imageView.setPreserveRatio(true);
        imageView.setFitHeight(100);
        imageView.setFitWidth(100);
        imageView.fitHeightProperty().bind(imageList.heightProperty());
        imageList.getChildren().add(imageView);

    }

    @FXML
    void finishButtonHandler(ActionEvent event) {

    }

    @FXML
    void leftButtonHandler(ActionEvent event) {

    }

    @FXML
    void rightButtonHandler(ActionEvent event) {

    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {

    }
}
```

Comment: work through a tutorial on fx basics

Answer (score 2):

**Resizing with polygon shape**

[image]

As you can see the image can be stretched but is resizable . The trick is bind bidrectionally x and y translate property from group object (parent of polygon) to FitHeightProperty and FitWidth property from imageview object

this is a single functional javafx app you can try

**App.java**

```
public class App extends Application {
    
    private double startX;
    private double startY;
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView("https://ioppublishing.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/cat-web-cc0.jpg");
        imageView.setFitHeight(436);
        imageView.setFitWidth(560);
        
        Group handler = makeHandler();
        handler.translateXProperty().bindBidirectional(imageView.fitWidthProperty());
        handler.translateYProperty().bindBidirectional(imageView.fitHeightProperty());
        
        Group imageGroup = new Group(imageView, handler);
        
        StackPane stackPane = new StackPane(imageGroup);
        Scene scene = new Scene(stackPane, 800, 600);
        stage.setTitle("Resizing image");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
        
    }
    
    private Group makeHandler() {
        
        Polygon polygon = new Polygon();
        Group group = new Group(polygon);
        polygon.getPoints().addAll(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -20.0, -20.0, 0.0);
        polygon.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        polygon.setFill(Color.AZURE);
        
        polygon.setStrokeWidth(2);
        polygon.setStrokeType(StrokeType.INSIDE);
        
        group.setOnMousePressed(e -> {
            
            startX = group.getLayoutX() - e.getX();
            startY = group.getLayoutY() - e.getY();
            
        });
        
        group.setOnMouseDragged(e -> {
            group.setTranslateX(group.getTranslateX() + e.getX() + startX);
            group.setTranslateY(group.getTranslateY() + e.getY() + startY);
            
        });        
        
        return group;
    }
}
```